# Display Outline on Layer in photoshop

Tags: adobe, photo, photoshop, layer

This must be a very noob question, but via googling I am getting different answers.

I just want that via layer panel when I click on any layer,
there must be selection outline between all the layers, that which layer is selected.

I have used Adobe fireworks somewhat, and in it I can easily see the selected layer via just clicking on it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+*click* the layer thumbnail, which I highlighted below (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+*click* on Mac)

[image: Highlighted area: layer thumbnail]

**Don't click on the layer name,** it will select the layer but it won't show you the outline. Before clicking, your cursor should be a hand with an outline.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 22):

**On Windows Photoshop cs5.**

```
View->Show->Layer Edges
```

When you select a layer it will now show the edges in blue. You can select multiple layers to see multiple outlines.

Also slightly off topic but if you want to click directly on the canvas to select an item similar to how Fireworks does. You can select the move tool and click the "**Auto-Select**" option at the top of the screen. Change the dropdown to "**Layer**" instead of "**Group**" if you want to select individual layers.

Comment: Wow, this is changing my life - Photoshop alignment never made sense for me until I could see my layers... thanks

Comment: I didn't know about that, it's almost perfect except that it's not the actual layer edges, it sets the edges by the pixel content of the image so doesn't include blank space around the layer. If you select transform you can see the actual edges. With placed images I need to see the real edges, I don't suppose there's any way do do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could ctrl+click a layer to get a selection of it. This can help visualize all it's opaque area/coverage. (note that pixels with low opacity might not be shown)

Comment: +1 but this will select the layer, it wont show marquee selection

Answer (score 2):

For shapes only, a nice trick you can do once you see outline of the shape is hitting Ctrl + Enter (if you don't see it, Ctrl + H will reveal it). For Macs, the shortcut is Cmd + Enter.